# 1 column txt/csv with strange layout to "normal" table layout mysql

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a strange and not normalized csv/txt file.

Somehow all the examples I found for processing csv data is for normalized csv data that has all the values in a row, thats not helping me, with solving this strange format.

The values will be past in a textbox and processed and saved to a `mysql table / php`, it's a `1 (1 title, 1 value)` column data set.

The title is separated with the value by a colon `(:)`. Not always are all the field-names with values used, as shown underneath, the "group" of values is separated by an empty line.

What I try to accomplish is to store the values in a mysql table with field-names in the row:

> status : history
>  date : 01-01-2012
>  user : Mr x
>  code :
>   A1
>  Explanation : blablabal
>  fixed : 02-01-2012
>  count :
>   1
>  cost : 12,00
>  boss : Mr B
>  number1 : 123
>  number2 :
>   456
>  verification : 789
>
> status : history
>  date : 01-01-2012
>  user : Mr x
>  code :
>   X10
>  Explanation : didididi
>  fixed : 02-01-2012
>  count :
>   1
>  cost : 22,00
>  boss : Mr B
>  number1 : 123
>  number2 :
>   456
>  verification : 789
>
> date : 04-02-2012
>  user : A1
>  explanation : doedoedoe
>
> status : history
>  date : 01-01-2012
>  user : Mr x
>  code :
>   F12
>  Explanation : nananaan
>  fixed : 02-01-2012
>  count :
>   1
>  cost : 120,00
>  boss : Mr B
>  number1 : 123
>  number2 :
>   456
>  verification : 789

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: With parsecsv i can use conditions, this is working but not a safe way to do it i guess